# &amp; instead of & in STUFF FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `STUFF` function. I have some entries having **&** but shows **&amp ;** instead. Somewhere I read that & is reserved in XML. How to solve this.

```
...STUFF((SELECT (', ' + CategoryName) FROM CategoryTable WHERE CategoryId IS NOT NULL AND CategoryId IN (1,2,3) FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as CategoryName,...
```

Above is my query (Well I have just added a part of a full query.). How to solve. Thanks.

Comment: You can always just do a simple `replace`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The wrong way:

```
SELECT  STUFF(
            (
                SELECT  ', ' + v.name
                FROM    (
                    VALUES
                        ('bonnie & clyde'),
                        ('thelma & louise')
                )v(NAME)
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '')
```

The jedi path:

```
SELECT  STUFF(
            (
                SELECT  ', ' + v.name
                FROM    (
                    VALUES
                        ('bonnie & clyde'),
                        ('thelma & louise')
                )v(NAME)
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
```

Comment: can you share reference for the way you described.?

Comment: That's just an unsafe casting. `.value` and so on can be found in general MSSQL documentation for XML datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Use this ..

```
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
```